# Regex match pattern up to a "."

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use a regex to match a string up to a period. For example I have this string

```
Updated IVR Info response to :Answered but No Response. Locked for IVR processing. 
Updated IVR Info response to :Yes. Locked for IVR processing.
Updated IVR Info response to :No. Locked for IVR processing.
```

I want my match collection to contain 3 strings.

```
Answered but No Response
No
Yes
```

What i tried..

```
string pattern = "Updated IVR Info response to :.+?/.";

Regex r = new Regex(pattern);

var matches = r.Matches(item.Information);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a lookbehind in your regex:

```
string pattern = "(?<=Updated IVR Info response to :)[^.]+";
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eI7gQ1/1)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're escaping your '.' the wrong way:

```
"Updated IVR Info response to :.+?\\.";
```

To get the actual values, use a group:

```
string pattern = "Updated IVR Info response to :(.+?\\.)";

Regex r = new Regex(pattern);

var values = r.Matches(item.Information).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value);
```

Output:

> Answered but No Response.
>   Yes.
>   No.

Comment: Mention how to use the `@` to use the C# string literalto avoid  having to having to do double escapes (`\\`) in a pattern.